# What is the preferred way to specify an HTTP "Location" Response Header in Spring MVC 3?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

What is the preferred way to specify an HTTP "Location" Response Header in Spring MVC 3?

As far as I can tell, Spring will only provide a "Location" in response to a redirect ("redirect:xyz" or RedirectView), however there are scenarios where a Location should be sent along with the entity body (ex, as a result of a "201 Created").

I'm afraid my only option is manually specifying it:

```
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Location", "/x/y/z");
```

Is this correct?  Is there a better way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Whats wrong with that approach?

Comment: That's the good way of doing it, and it conforms to the [http specs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30).

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The key point is to use `UriComponentsBuilder`.
There are several ways how you can get the instance of it

1. preconfigured `UriComponentsBuilder` from `MvcUriComponentsBuilder`
2. `UriComponentsBuilder` injected as parameter to method

### Preconfigured `UriComponentsBuilder` from `MvcUriComponentsBuilder`

This way you can get `UriComponentsBuilder` that is configured to produce `URI` that points to some controller methods with predefined parameters.

Here is example from the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/MvcUriComponentsBuilder.html#fromMethodCall-java.lang.Object-) for `MvcUriComponentsBuilder`:

For example, given this controller:

```
 @RequestMapping("/people/{id}/addresses")
 class AddressController {

   @RequestMapping("/{country}")
   public HttpEntity<Void> getAddressesForCountry(@PathVariable String country) { ... }

   @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public void addAddress(Address address) { ... }
 }
```

A UriComponentsBuilder can be created:

```
 // Inline style with static import of "MvcUriComponentsBuilder.on"

 MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMethodCall(
    on(AddressController.class).getAddressesForCountry("US")).buildAndExpand(1);
```

Another options which sometimes may be preferable is to specify controller method by name:

```
UriComponents uriComponents = MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMethodName(
    AddressController.class, "getAddressesForCountry", "US").buildAndExpand(1);
URI nextUri = uriComponents.toUri();
```

### `UriComponentsBuilder` injected as parameter to method

As of spring 3.1 `Location` can be crafted using `UriComponentBuilder` parameter and set it to the returned `ResponseEntity`. `UriComponentBuilder` is aware of the context and manipulates with relative paths:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> createCustomer(UriComponentsBuilder b) {

    UriComponents uriComponents = 
        b.path("/customers/{id}").buildAndExpand(id);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setLocation(uriComponents.toUri());
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Since version 4.1 you can make it even shorter

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> createCustomer(UriComponentsBuilder b) {

    UriComponents uriComponents = 
        b.path("/customers/{id}").buildAndExpand(id);

    return ResponseEntity.created(uriComponents.toUri()).build();
}
```

Thanks to Dieter Hubau to pointing this out.

Comment: There's a syntax error on the headers.setLocation line. There's an extra closing parens and "id" doesn't exist. Just wanted to point out to others who come across this answer, this isn't a complete method that will compile. But thanks for the answer, it's helpful.

Comment: Excellent answer, you can even make it a bit shorter now:

`return ResponseEntity.created(uriComponents.toUri()).build();`

Comment: Is `UriComponentsBuilder` being injected? Can it be `@Autowire`d?

Comment: the uriComponent is not adding the port in the answer.
I always get http://locahost/resource/1 instead of http://localhost:9090/resource/1

Answer (score 40):

The following example is from spring tutorial:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
ResponseEntity<?> add(@PathVariable String userId, @RequestBody Bookmark input) {
    this.validateUser(userId);

    return this.accountRepository
            .findByUsername(userId)
            .map(account -> {
                Bookmark result = bookmarkRepository.save(new Bookmark(account,
                        input.uri, input.description));

                URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
                    .fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}")
                    .buildAndExpand(result.getId()).toUri();

                return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
            })
            .orElse(ResponseEntity.noContent().build());

}
```

Take note that the following will compute the context path (URI) for you avoiding code duplication and making your application more portable:

```
ServletUriComponentsBuilder
                    .fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}")
```

Answer (score 6):

It's an old question but here is what you can do if you want to let Spring really build the URI for you.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
class JobsController {

  @PostMapping("/jobs")
  fun createJob(@RequestParam("use-gpu") useGPU: Boolean?): ResponseEntity<Unit> {

    val headers = HttpHeaders()

    val jobId = "TBD id"

    headers.location =
            MvcUriComponentsBuilder
                    .fromMethodName(JobsController::class.java, "getJob", jobId)
                    .buildAndExpand(jobId)
                    .toUri()

    return ResponseEntity(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED)
  }

  @GetMapping("/job/{jobId}")
  fun getJob(@PathVariable jobId: String) = ... // fetch job
}
```

In this example (which is written in Kotlin but similar for java), the base URI is `/api/v1` (defined at the top of the class). Using `MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMethodName` call lets Spring figure out the proper full URI. (`MvcUriComponentsBuilder` was added in 4.0).

Answer (score 2):

According to: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30

Absolute URI should be used:

```
Location       = "Location" ":" absoluteURI
```

And the **URI** should be escaped properly:

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt

Comment: The documented you refer to is obsolete. The superseded final [RFC 7231 §7.12](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-7.1.2)  makes it clear the value can be _relative_.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems fine, but to keep it clean you could put the code inside a custom `HandlerInterceptor` that only triggers when there's an HTTP 201, for example.

See [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-interceptors) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. For some reason, it's pretty hard to find information about it among all the superficial details.