# Return a 302 status code in Spring MVC Controller

Tags: spring, http-status-code-302

I am developing a Spring MVC app, and I need to check in my controller a certain condition. In case it were true, I have to return a 302 status code. It's something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mypath.shtml", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView pageHandler(@Valid MyForm form, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request,
        Locale locale) throws PageControllerException, InvalidPageContextException, ServiceException {

    if (someCondition){
        // return 302 status code
    }
    else{
        // Do some stuff
    }
}
```

Which is the best way to do this?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Note that a 302 is not an error, but you still might be able to use Spring's exception framework to map an exception type to 302.

Comment: Sorry about it, I have changed the "error" word for status code

Comment: I found the way to do it that works perfectly for me. I posted the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally managed to do it using `@ResponseStatus`, as shown here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2067043/2982518

**UPDATE**

This is the way I finally did it:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.MOVED_TEMPORARILY)
public class MovedTemporarilyException extends RuntimeException {

    // ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/mypath.shtml", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView pageHandler(@Valid MyForm form, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request,
        Locale locale) throws PageControllerException, InvalidPageContextException, ServiceException {

    if (someCondition){
        throw new MovedTemporarilyException();
    }
    else{
        // Do some stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: That will change the status in all conditions. Not  just for the condition you mentioned. What I mean is that even if your condition is not true, it will still return 302

Comment: @geoand I am only going to throw this exception in case my condition were true, otherwise I'll do whatever I need. I updated my answer to show you how.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying! Both solutions will work

Comment: how did you setup the url to send as it's a redirect?

Comment: @Panthro I don't understand your question, could you explain it clearer?

Comment: When you have a redirect, the `Location` header has to be sent, how did you do it? (Sorry, it was really bad phrased)

Comment: Check at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318912/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-specify-an-http-location-response-header-in-sprin/15898426#15898426), I think it is what you are looking for

Comment: Why is HttpStatus.MOVED_TEMPORARILY now deprecated?

Answer (score 3):

The following code will do:

```
if (someCondition){
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + someUrl)
}
else{
        // Do some stuff
}
```

Comment: I found the way to do it that works perfectly for me. I posted the answer

Answer (score 1):

`org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView` has a few simple parameters. One of the parameters removes the model attributes from the URL.

The previous answers worked for me, but the redirect Location header was including the model attributes added by some interceptor post methods.

```
return new RedirectView(newLocationVia302, true, true, false);
```